# Can you connect multiple USB Credit Card Readers to a single PC?

Tags: credit-card

I realize this might not be the best setup, but humor me, is it possible to connect multiple USB Credit Card Readers to a single PC? Have anyone tried this before? How do you differentiate the data between the different readers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB MSRs (magnetic stripe readers) are often set up as "HID" devices, which means that input looks just like it's coming in over the keyboard. If you need to have multiple, you want USB MSRs that have drivers that do other things.

A common solution is to have drivers that make the input come in on a virtual serial port, selected at driver install time, one port per device. So, if you do that, you would differentiate by listening on two different COM ports.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the model of the reader and the drivers provided.  There would probably be a way to identify the individual readers but it could be vendor-specific, and the software that going to use the readers would have to be configurable to handle it.